# Special comments permissions

Tags: 7, views, comments

I'm trying to restrict the comment permissions as follows:

- Any user can view **own comments** and any **reply** to his comments on a node.
- **Node Author** can view all comments on his node.

Is it possible to achieve this using **Views**?

#### Update:

I'm considering doing this with [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module as it seems to do what I want out of box.